# How to zoom in and zoom out terminal console in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I am able to zoom in the Ubuntu Terminal by Pressing Ctrl - Shift and ++ . But I donot know how to zoom out the Ubuntu Terminal.

Is there any short-cuts available for doing so?

[image: Command Prompt]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this following method:

- Zoom In :  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
- Zoom Out:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- Zoom 100%:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, that will only zoom in. how to zoom out then?

Comment: Yep! It worked like a charm!. Carry on this Good Work!

Comment: Most Welcome _--_

Comment: Neutral is `Ctrl - 0(zero)`

Answer (score 4):

To zoom in do

> ctrl Shift +

To zoom out do

> ctrl -

Answer (score 2):

Try the following keystrokes
`Ctrl` + `-`

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl` + `-` doesn't work for me. But a workaround is to change the shortcut for the `Zoom Out` action.

Right click on the terminal and select `Preferences`. Then `Shortcuts`. Then change the `Shortcut Key` for `Zoom Out` to whatever you want. I chose `Ctrl` + `Backspace`.

Answer (score 0):

i cant use Ctrl Shift + for zoom in